# Cannot convert int[] array to int[]

Tags: java, arrays, vector, int

I continue to get the error that the array I'm passing as a parameter on line 27 cannot be converted to an int[], though I've declared it as such. Could anyone explain to me why this is?
[Compiler Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0icyg.png)

```
import java.util.*;

class C10E3
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //declaration phase
        int[] array ={4, 23, 65, 34, 82, 37, 12, 17, 24, 36, 82, 51};
        int[] arrayUpdated = new int[11];
        int intToBeRemoved;
        int intCounter;
        Remover remove = new Remover();

        System.out.println("Which of these elements shalls be removed from thr array?");
        //display array
        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 12; intCounter++)
            System.out.print(array[intCounter]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        //determine int to be removed
        intToBeRemoved = console.nextInt();
        //call method remove to remove int
        arrayUpdated = remove.removeItem(array, 12, intToBeRemoved);
        System.out.print("Updated Array: ");
        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 11; intCounter++)
            System.out.print(array[intCounter]);
    }
}

class Remover
{
    private Vector vector = new Vector();

    public void removeItem(int[] array, int intArrayLength, int intToRemove)
    {
        boolean boolIsRemoved;
        int intCounter;

        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < intArrayLength; intCounter++)
            vector.addElement(array[intCounter]);

        boolIsRemoved = vector.removeElement(intToRemove);
        if (boolIsRemoved == true)
            {
                vector.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Element not present in array.");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please inline the compiler message in the question

Comment: Your title and your error message are not the same

Answer (score 1):

`arrayUpdated = remove.removeItem(array, 12, intToBeRemoved);`

`public void removeItem(int[] array, int intArrayLength, int intToRemove)`

the return type of `removeItem()` is void, you can't assign it to `arrayUpdated`

Answer (score 1):

your error comes from this line:

```
arrayUpdated = remove.removeItem(array, 12, intToBeRemoved);
```

your `removeItem()` method returns void, and you are trying to assign it to a variable.